# Interrupt to run a new dialog on Botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to migrate my codes from the old Bot Framework V4(last January) to the new Bot framework v4 design. What I like is to call a dialog when the user input. "Get started". I can do this easily on the previous design but now I can't. Also this is just text now. what if i want to use a LUIS intent? Thank you.

```
        protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnBeginDialogAsync(
                       DialogContext innerDc, 
                       object options, 
                       CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return await base.OnBeginDialogAsync(innerDc, options, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(
                             DialogContext innerDc, 
                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(
                   DialogContext innerDc, 
                   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

            switch (text)
            {
                case "help":
                case "?":
                    await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Show Help...",
                          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);

                case "get started":
                    return await innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DialogA));

                case "cancel":
                case "quit":
                    await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Cancelling",
                          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

DialogA

```
    namespace practiceNewBot.Dialogs
{
    public class DialogA : CancelAndHelpDialog
    {
        public DialogA() : base(nameof(DialogA))
        {
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                FirstStepAsync,
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"start of dialog a"), cancellationToken);

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            nameof(ChoicePrompt),
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"choose a dialog"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>
                     {
                            new Choice
                            {
                                Value = "Dialog A Child",
                                Synonyms = new List<string>
                                {
                                    "dialog a child",
                                },
                            },
                            new Choice
                            {
                                Value = "Dialog B Child",
                                Synonyms = new List<string>
                                {
                                    "dialog b chilc",
                                },
                            },
                            new Choice
                            {
                                Value = "Cancel",
                                Synonyms = new List<string>
                                {
                                    "cancel",
                                },
                            },
                     },
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please choose one of the options."),
            },
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice).Value.ToLower();

            switch (response)
            {
                case "dialog a child":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DialogA), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                case "dialog b child":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DialogB), cancellationToken);

                case "cancel":
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Ok, Cancelled."));
                    return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                default:
                    break;
            }

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"end of dialog a"), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for DialogA too please.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: What about the code inside `FirstStepAsync`? I assume you are returning a `DialogTurnResult`? We will need to see this code as well in order to debug the issue.

Comment: @MattStannett Thank you. I don't have access to the computer now. will update the question tomorrow.

Comment: @MattStannett i have updated it.